# Use C# objects instead of HTML tags

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Is it possible to use instances of C# classes instead of HTML tags in Blazor WASM? So instead of writing

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
```

I would like to write something like

```
var button1 = new Button() { CssClass="btn btn-primary", OnClick=IncrementCount, Title="Click me" }
```

And tags like DIV would have a list of children to attach subtags:

```
myDiv.Children.Add(button1);
```

Is this approach even feasible?

Comment: Because I hate mixing languages in a project and especially in one file. My last line of code shows how I imagine adding a button to a DIV.

Comment: 'mixing languages' is the core of every Web framework. It has to happen somewhere, somehow. Razor makes it rather fluent and easy, don't fight it. You do know about code-behind ( .razor.cs) files?

Comment: [Polite] "Because I hate mixing languages in a project".  How do you then propose to write HTML from a C# file?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Same way any layout engine deals with HTML without writing HTML, by treating it as an object oriented tree.  Just look at HTML Agility Pack for example.  Other than front end apps, most middle ware actually doesn't use HTML literal strings anywhere

Answer (score 0):

In Blazor WebAssembly, the preferred way to define user interface elements is by using HTML tags and components. The approach you mentioned, using instances of C# classes instead of HTML tags, is not directly supported in Blazor.

Blazor follows a component-based architecture, where you define UI components using a combination of HTML markup and C# code. Components encapsulate their own logic and rendering, and they are typically defined using a combination of HTML and C# code.

However, if you want a more programmatic way to create UI elements dynamically, you can achieve that by using conditional rendering and component composition in Blazor. For example, you can create a component that accepts a list of child components as a parameter and dynamically renders them. Here's an example:

```
<!-- ParentComponent.razor -->
@foreach (var child in childComponents)
{
    <div>@child</div>
}

@code {
    private List<RenderFragment> childComponents = new List<RenderFragment>();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var button1 = new RenderFragment(builder =>
        {
            builder.OpenElement(0, "button");
            builder.AddAttribute(1, "class", "btn btn-primary");
            builder.AddAttribute(2, "onclick", EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, IncrementCount));
            builder.AddContent(3, "Click me");
            builder.CloseElement();
        });

        childComponents.Add(button1);
    }

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        // Increment logic here
    }
}`
```

In this example, the ParentComponent dynamically renders child components based on the childComponents list. You can create the child components programmatically using the RenderFragment class and the builder parameter in the RenderFragment.

While this approach allows you to dynamically create components, it's important to note that Blazor's design philosophy is centered around the use of HTML tags and components for defining the user interface. Using HTML tags and components provides better separation of concerns, code readability, and reusability.